# How to read a file line by line and put them as a variable?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, variable, readline

im very new to linux and shell scripting. May I know how do you read a file line by line and pass each line as a variable?

For example, lets say i have a file called **abc.txt** with these 2 lines as its content.

> Documents
>
> Slides

And now I want to pass these 2 as variables D and S, whereby

> D = Documents
>
> S = Slides

How do i do this? Assuming I know beforehand that the file only have 2 lines and that the variables are always D and S.

Comment: Do you know beforehand that your file contains exactly two lines? Or do you want the first two lines only? Should the variables always be `D` and `S`? If you want to read more lines, how do you choose the variable names? Please [edit] your question and add more information or explanation. For your specific example you could use `{read D;read S} < abc.txt`

Answer (score -1):

Yes.It's possible.

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS="
"
for i in `cat abc.txt | grep .`; do  x=`echo $i | head -c 1`; declare "$x"="$i" ; done
```

Scrot

[image: shot]